# font-display not fixing Page Speed Insights issue

Tags: css, optimization, fonts, pagespeed, lighthouse

I am trying to improve the performance of my website and I am starting with the suggestions that Google Page Speed Insights is giving me.

I seem unable to solve this issue though:

[image]

It suggests using the `font-display` CSS property on this page - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/font-display

I have done this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Malaga OT Reg';
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('./MalagaOT-Reg.eot');
  src: url('./MalagaOT-Reg.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./MalagaOT-Reg.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./MalagaOT-Reg.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./MalagaOT-Reg.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Rounded';
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('./MuseoSansRounded-300.eot');
  src: url('./MuseoSansRounded-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-300.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-300.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-300.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Rounded';
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('./MuseoSansRounded-900.eot');
  src: url('./MuseoSansRounded-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-900.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-900.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-900.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Rounded';
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('./MuseoSansRounded-700.eot');
  src: url('./MuseoSansRounded-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-700.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-700.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-700.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Rounded';
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('./MuseoSansRounded-100.eot');
  src: url('./MuseoSansRounded-100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-100.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-100.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-100.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Rounded';
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('./MuseoSansRounded-500.eot');
  src: url('./MuseoSansRounded-500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-500.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-500.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./MuseoSansRounded-500.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo';
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('./Museo-700.eot');
  src: url('./Museo-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./Museo-700.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./Museo-700.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./Museo-700.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./Museo-700.svg#Museo-700') format('svg');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo';
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('./Museo500-Regular.eot');
  src: url('./Museo500-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./Museo500-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./Museo500-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./Museo500-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('./Museo500-Regular.svg#Museo500-Regular') format('svg');
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo';
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('./Museo900-Regular.eot');
  src: url('./Museo900-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./Museo900-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('./Museo900-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./Museo900-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('./Museo900-Regular.svg#Museo900-Regular') format('svg');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

But it has not made a difference to the PageSpeed report. I have tried both `swap` and `fallback` values for the `font-display` property.

Is anyone able to offer any advice for how I can solve this issue?

Comment: `font-display:optional` should do the trick.

Comment: Just tried. Sadly, it didn't help :(

Comment: Odd, seeing that the `font-display` properties with values of `swap`, `optional` and `fallback` do not cause a **FOIT** (Flash Of Invisible Text). Only `font-display: block` causes a FOIT. More info can be found [here](https://font-display.glitch.me/)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it works with `font-display: swap;` but it may take days for the PSI report to note your improvement, especially Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the woff2 and only keep woff format.
2. set font-display property to block;

   font-display: block;
3. Optionally you can remove tiff and eot reference as well to speed up the site.

Answer (score 0):

hey I was having exact same issues. Then I added this piece of code to my style.css and the customise > additional css sections of my theme and Google stopped firing those warnings:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
  src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans");
  font-display: swap;
}
```